# How's the right way to pipe stdout & stderr from ping into an awk program?

Tags: awk, zsh, xargs

Here's an excerpt of some commands that I've been trying to evaluate from a Zsh script:

```
cmd="ping -qc 3 -W 5 8.8.8.8 | xargs -0d '\n' awk -f presetup/testping.awk 2>&1"
print -r ${cmd}
output=$(eval ${cmd})
print ${output}
```

I don't know what I'm missing but, all I'm trying to do is to process the stderr & stdout of ping with a single awk script.  Here's the output I'm getting:

```
awk: presetup/testping.awk:6: fatal: cannot open file `PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The program is supposed to parse each output line of the ping command and match with regular expressions its output.  Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: `xargs` is wrong there, you have to pipe stdout and stderr to `awk`.

Comment: @karakfa, thanks for your input.  I removed `xargs` and tried this: `ping -qc 3 -W 5 8.8.8.8 2>&1 awk -f presetup/testping.awk -` without success.  I had the following output: `ping: -: Name or service not known`.

Comment: @karakfa, nevermind, I found it.  The right way seems to be the following: `ping -qc 3 -W 5 8.8.8.8 | 2>&1 awk -f presetup/testping.awk -`  Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for pointing me into the right direction @karakfa. It seems that the right way is as follows:

```
ping -qc 3 -W 5 8.8.8.8 2>&1 | awk -f presetup/testping.awk
```

OR:

```
ping -qc 3 -W 5 8.8.8.8 |& awk -f presetup/testping.awk
```